# pg dump output the schema name and the data

Tags: postgresql, database-backups, pgadmin, pg-dump

when i use (pg_dump -f backup.sql mydb), the schema name are not included. How to dump that will output also the scheme name(personal). see example below

Output : `ALTER TYPE basicinfo OWNER TO postgres;`
// note : basicinfo is the name of the table

Expected Output : `ALTER TYPE personal.basicinfo OWNER TO postgres;`

any ideas?

Comment: If you go through the first few lines of the dump, you will see lines like SET search_path = personal. That should ensure that the rights objects are chosen. May be you wanted to explicitly mention schema name for some other reason?

Comment: Thanks Jayadevan, but you are right that i want to explicitly mention the schema name also. I been restore a database.sql with same format(schema name included) and want to backup like the same format. Is there other way?

Answer (score 3):

Global Database properties such as OWNER etc. are always given with SCHEMA names in a pg_dump output.

However, for non-global database objects, as far as I know, there isn't any way to get `SCHEMA` names prepended to all the database objects. The way the script works is that it sets the `SET search_path` before-hand all Schema specific database objects... which is more efficient and has the same effect.

In case you are trying to parse an pg_dump output to extract a given SQL line that works independently, you may have to also parse the nearest-preceding `SET search_path` line and execute that before executing the target line (for e.g. `ALTER TYPE`) to have the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

You cant do that using pg_dump directly.
Try to use different tools, They have different implementation for exporting PostgreSQL database.

Here are list of tools:

1. phpPgAdmin - http://sourceforge.net/projects/phppgadmin
2. AnySQL Maestro - http://www.sqlmaestro.com/products/anysql/maestro/
3. DBeaver -  http://dbeaver.jkiss.org/

All refence: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Community_Guide_to_PostgreSQL_GUI_Tools